# Python Variable keeping it's value across multiple functions

Tags: python, function, variables, nested

I am writing a program where I have a value that is 0 at the start, but is used throughout the program to keep track of "changes" and I want then to print the sum of the changes, the rest of the code works fine but for some reason that variable that goes into multiple functions doesn't keep the changes and return them when I print but just returns 0 every time

```
var = 0

def func1(var1):
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            if condition:
                pass
            elif condition:
                func2(var1)
    return var1

def func2(var2):
    if condition:
        pass
    elif condition:
        var2 += 1
    return var2

func1(var)
print(var)
```

Comment: You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You return `var2` in `func2` but you don't catch the value in `func1`. Maybe you want `var1 = func2(var1)`?

Comment: @chepner: thanks for this link, it's a very interesting read, very well explained, even for someone who already knows the basics!

Comment: @Matthias i want to catch the value in func1 and ultimately return the cumulative value from inside the functions to the var variable outside

Answer (score 6):

`int` values are immutable, and Python does not use call-by-reference semantics. `var2 += 1` sets the *local* variable `var2` to refer to an `int` object equal to `var2 + 1`. It neither mutates the value originally assigned to `var2`, not updates the variable used to pass a value to `func2` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in `var` to `func1()` as `var1`, manipulating the value of var1 and returning the value of `var1`.  However, you do not assign a variable to the return of `func1()`.  Since you are not manipulating `var` itself, just its value inside of `func1()`, when you print `var` at the end, you still get its original value. Try this:

```
output = func1(var)
print(output) # will print an updated value - I can't say what value as I don't know x and y
print(var) # will still print 0 as you are not actually modifying var itself.
```

If inside of `func1()` you did not pass in arguments and instead were operating on `var` instead of the argument `var1`, var would get changed.  But in python you are simply modifying the value you pass in, not the actual value of the variable.

I recommend researching pass-by-value, pass-by-reference, and how python handles these things.